# Designing a 'Restaurant System' using Php

Tags: php, compatibility

Is it advisable or even possible to design a restaurant system using php? The system requires one to make an order that is printed to the chef and manager, the order stays pending until checked-out by the counter.

My worry is not the system specification, but the ability of php to implement it, especially when it comes to command the printing option after the order has been made. i was thnking of using symphony...but the whole issue seems not compatible with php (the language am most good at)

Any suggestions?

:)

thanx.

Comment: thats what am looking for, how impossible it is to design such a system with php....then if they are any gr8 suggestions i'll appresiate :)

Comment: Claiming that PHP can do anything, as is done at http://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatcando.php, is perhaps a bit presumptuous, but I'm pretty sure you can use it to write a restaurant system like that mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just buy a few clearance 42" tvs which all display a syndication feed of the orders. Have the checkout app provide the syndication feed (be online or local, whatever). Would be cheaper than dev costs of implementing a sync and print system and much cooler. ;-)

As for your question about using PHP, it's possible and seems reasonable. Symfony could be used for the checkout app, but for printing in the kitchen you'll probably want to use shell scripts (or php as a shell script).

Comment: Nice idea, i thnk the best thing i'l do is create a page for the chef and manager, printing will be on their own consent, based on your idea...instead of putting a tv why not put a normal PC so that at least there can be interaction - and the chef tells everyone that the order is ready :)